Automatically populate a cell whilst retaining data validation drop-down?
I have a Google Sheet that is tracking various requests that come into our team and one of the columns is a data validated drop down list column showing whether the request is 'pending allocation', 'in progress', 'completed' etc.
The requests come in via a Google Form and this Google Sheet is import ranging directly from that. What I would like to do is have the status column automatically validate as 'pending allocation' each time a new request comes in and then one of the team can manually override that once it has been allocated. By using ISBLANK I was able to get the column to populate with 'pending allocation' once a corresponding request came in but the problem is this then overwrote the data validation that I and preset.
Is there any way I can configure the sheet so that when column X is populated with a new request, my status column can populate with 'awaiting allocation' but retain the data validation drop down?
TLDR: Whenever Column A is popualted, I want column D on the same row to automatically change to 'Pending Allocation' whilst retaining the data validation drop-down list. Can anyone help?
Sample Spreadsheet

This is something you need to do through Apps Script.

Here is a sample Apps Script that will do what you specified.
function onEdit(e) {
  // Get the sheetname of the sheet being edited
  var activeSheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var activeSheetName = activeSheet.getName();

  // We only want to edit 'Build Sample Here' sheet
  if (activeSheetName !== 'Build Sample Here') return;

  // Get preset validation
  var validationCell = activeSheet.getRange('D2');
  var validation = validationCell.getDataValidation();

  if (validation == null) return;

  // Get validation choices
  var choices = validation.getCriteriaValues(); // Array[][]
  var pendingAllocation = choices[0][0]

  // Check that e.range is column A and value is empty
  if (e.range.getColumn() != 1.0 || e.oldValue != null) return;

  // Otherwise, set Status on row to 'Pending Allocation'
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const dropdown = activeSheet.getRange(row, 4);
  dropdown.setValue(pendingAllocation);
}


Thank you @Streeter this was so helpful! Do you know why it won't work in conjunction with a QUERY formula? If I just type something into a cell in column A, it works great and automatically populates 'Pending Allocation' in column D but if I'm using a QUERY in column A to pull through data from another sheet (which is ideally what I want to do), then it doesn't populate column D. Is there any edit to the script that would fix this? Thanks again so much for your help

Try renaming the function from OnEdit(e) to something like setPendingStatus(e) and then install the script using a trigger, where the event type is "On Edit." Here is a post with something similar MontyThePython's answer is what I'm referring to.

So I'm using the original script that you provided except for OnEdit(e) is renamed to setPendingStatus(e) and I have then set up a Trigger to run setPendingStatus(e) with On Edit as the event type but unfortunately it doesn't work. In the execution log is keeps failing with the error 'Script function not found: setPendingStatus' - am I missing something obvious?
